# Can the id command query Active Directory for a uid?

Tags: active-directory, osx-yosemite, freebsd

If I run `id 1000001` (freebsd or mac), configured to authenticate with Active Directory, it returns `id: 1000001: no such user`.

Running `id DOMAIN\\user1` returns the info correctly, after which I can also run `id 1000001` and it then works.

The *nix admins have asked me to check AD, but I'm not sure that is the problem. Will the id command actually do a uid lookup in Active Directory or is this not possible? Local uid lookups work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both username and UID lookups use the same configuration (/etc/nsswitch.conf on Linux, similar on FreeBSD, or whatever stuff OS X has invented).

But UID lookups depend on how your AD client is configured.

Last I checked, Samba/winbindd's default mode is to allocate UIDs *locally* (in a `/var/lib/samba` database) instead of basing them on AD information, and naturally you cannot look up an UID that hasn't been allocated yet. If you're using Samba as the AD client, take a look at the `idmap_rid(8)`, `idmap_autorid(8)`, `idmap_ad(8)`, `idmap_nss(8)` backends.